# Remove all elements from associative array Bash

Tags: bash

I need to remove all of the keys and values from an associative array in Bash. `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.  I cannot just `unset` it, because I need to do this inside a function.  If I unset it, and then `declare` it again, it will only be local to the function.

```
arrayFunction()
{
    # Start the array Clearer
    unset workingArray
    declare -A workingArray
    # End the array Clearer

    workingArray[test]="bar"
    echo "Inside the function: ${workingArray[test]}"
}

declare -A workingArray

workingArray[test]="foo"

echo "Before the function: ${workingArray[test]}"

arrayFunction

echo "After the function: ${workingArray[test]}"
```

Output:

```
Before the function: foo
Inside the function: bar
After the function:
```

That last line of the output should be `bar`.

What I am looking for is some code to put inside the function that will empty the array ENTIRELY, while keeping the array global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it's not really complex, just use `-g`.

Inside your function:

```
declare -gA workingArray
```

and this will happen gloabally.

Comment: Wow.  Obviously there would be something so stupidly simple, that I could have found in like 5 seconds with `declare --help`.  Thank you!

Comment: More specifically, "When used in a function, declare makes each name local, as with the local command, unless the -g option is used"
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Answer (score 2):

The question ask to "remove all of the keys and values". However, from the sample code, it looks as if the request is to REPLACE all existing keys and values with new set of keys/values. This can be achieved with assignment to the associative array.

```
arrayFunction()
{
    workingArray=( [test]="bar" )
    echo "Inside the function: ${workingArray[test]}"
}
```

If the new key/values set is dynamic, it can be build incrementally

```
arrayFunction()
{
    # Start with empty set
    workingArray=()
    workingArray[test]=bar
    workingArray[lazy]=dog
    # Additional assignments
    echo "Inside the function: ${workingArray[test]}"
}
```

In both cases, there is no need to re-declare the array.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR: use `unset`

```
unset arr
declare -A arr # -g doesn't matter to the root of the question
```

#### Explanation

I found that `declare -gA arr` was insufficient if that array needed to be reset in the same scope. For example,

```
for file in `ls`; do
  declare -gA one_file
  safe_file=$(echo $file | tr '.' '_')  # simplified; mileage may vary
  one_file[${safe_file}]=foo
  printf "%s\n" "${!one_file[@]}"
done
```

outputs:

```
# what you'd expect if the array is never cleared out
(a lot of files -- file 1, file 2, ..., file i for i in range (1, N))
```

#### Solution

What works is `unset`:

```
for file in `ls`; do
  unset one_file
  declare -A one_file
  safe_file=$(echo $file | tr '.' '_')
  one_file["${safe_file}"]=foo
  printf "%s\n" "${!one_file[@]}"
done
```

Outputs each file 1 and only 1 time -- the array was cleared out each time.